# Java delete xml nodes using dom

Tags: java, xml, dom

I'm using dom to deal with my xml file, I have an input on the form

```
<students>
    <tableRow>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>ams</name>
        <grade>100</grade>
    </tableRow>
    <tableRow>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>ams</name>
        <grade>100</grade>
    </tableRow>
</students>
```

I want to delete all nodes to be on the form

```
<students>
</students>
```

I've tried the following code

```
Node node = doc.getFirstChild();
while (node.hasChildNodes())
    node.removeChild(node.getFirstChild());
```

and this one

```
NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("tableRow");
Node node = doc.getFirstChild();
for(int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++)
    node.removeChild(list.item(i));
```

but none of them worked. Any suggestions?

**update**
I got this exception

org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: An attempt is made to modify an object where modifications are not allowed.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.internalRemoveChild(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.removeChild(Unknown Source)

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work"? Did you get a exception?

Comment: If you don't write the modified DOM on the file, the file will not be changed.

Comment: @Kolja yes, I've updated the post

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna I write to the file but there was an exception, post updated

Comment: For which line of your first sample you get that exception? For which line of your second sample you get that exception? DOM `NodeList`s are live collection so you would need to remove items from the end of the NodeList in your loop `for (int i = list.getLength() - 1; i >=0; i--) { Node child = list.item(i); child.getParentNode().removeChild(child); }`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen the first code didn't give exception but it didn't work, the second gave exception in this line `node.removeChild(list.item(i));`. Your code worked, thanks so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the sample you have shown is your complete XML document then I think all you need is `doc.getDocumentElement().setTextContent("")` which will remove all child nodes of the document element.

Comment: Yes of course good idea, but unfortunately I need to count the deleted nodes.

Comment: Well `doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes().getLength()`, called before setting `textContent` to an empty string, will give you the number of child nodes.

Comment: Thanks so much, that's exactly what I've been trying to do

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been struggling to do this from 2 weeks.